# Django hstore field and index

Tags: python, django, postgresql, indexing, hstore

I'm using Django 1.8 and postgresql with the new hstore field. I'd like to apply an index to the values in my hstore field. However, reading postgres' documentation I got the feeling that a btree index isn't the way to go and a gin index is more appropriate because of the many values in my hstore field, all referring to the same record. using pgAdmin i noticed that if i add db_index=True to my hstore field it creates a btree index.
My questions are:

1. Would a btree index really be useless here and should i not use it?
2. I created a gin index using raw sql (planted in my migration) and I am wondering if thats enough, and whether my orm filter/get methods would work or do i have to override those as well

Raw SQL looks something like this:

```
SELECT * from transaction WHERE ("transaction"."hstorefield" -> 'service_code') = somevalue
```

Comment: I suggest using `jsonb` and PostgreSQL 9.4 these days. I view `hstore` as increasingly a legacy feature. As for indexing, you'd need to show the actual queries the ORM runs I think.

Comment: SELECT * from transaction WHERE ("transaction"."hstorefield" -> 'service_code') = somevalue

Answer (score 1):

GIN is fine though it does slow down inserts and updates substantially.

```
CREATE INDEX "ix_hsfield" ON "transaction" USING GIN ("hstorefield");
```

If you only need to speed up queries on one hstore key, a btree is possible and will be somewhat faster (and will work better on queries that use greater/less-than operators)

```
CREATE INDEX "ix_hsfieldkey" ON "transaction" ((hs_data -> 'service_code'));
```

if the key holds numeric data and you want to compare (less/greater than) with a number in your where clause, make sure you write the index like:

```
CREATE INDEX "ix_hsfieldkey" ON "transaction" ((hs_data -> 'service_code')::numeric);

-- the index won't be used unless the field used in the queries match the index:
SELECT * from transaction WHERE ("transaction"."hstorefield" -> 'service_code')::numeric = somevalue
```